# file.lis() returns "null" although it shouldn't

Tags: android, list, file, null, children

I'm working in a listActivity and I'm trying to show the children of a given directory. Here is what I've tried to get the children of a given directory :

```
    File currentFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "Pictures");
    String[] children = currentFile.list();
```

In fact, "children" is null and I don't know why. When I ask the absolute path of "currentFile", the answer is "/storage/emulated/0/Pictures".

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The document says **The result is null if this file is not a directory**. Try  `File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
            Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES);`

Comment: just add  `if(currentFile.exists() && currentFile.isDirectory()){ String[] children = currentFile.list(); }` check your self

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but it doesn't work :
"currentFile.exists()" returns "true",
"currentFile.isDirectory() returns "true" too, but still
"children == null" returns "true"...

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the folder exists, and check if you have added the permission to your manifest.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

and if you are running on Android M, you would need to request runtime permission

https://developer.android.com/preview/features/runtime-permissions.html#coding

Comment: Thanks but I already  added the permission to my manifest (someone else had the same problem on Stack Overflow too)

Comment: So, are you running on Android M? i.e. version 23 or android 6.0

Comment: No I'm not, my Android Version in just 5.0.2

Comment: Have you tried emulator? Also you may want to create a sample project on github, it would be easier for us to help.